# How does Google achieve this font thickness?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, typography

I have been trying to use the same font that Google uses on their menu but I can't seem to replicate the thickness that then have achieved.

As far as I can see the font specifics are as follows:

```
color: #FFF;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
```

I have used the same style but can't for the life of me figure out how they managed to 'thicken' the font so that it doesn't get lost in a dark background.

I have tried font weight 600 and that is too thick.

Here is a picture for as an example.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible that they have altered the 'Open Sans' font that they freely provide?

Comment: We can't answer to something we can't see. Need a link to where you see the Google thing.

Comment: are you using the exact same font resource? (not "CSS font-family", but resource - the actual file downloaded based on the @font-face rule)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see much difference myself, but you can increase a bit its weight  with a minimal text-shadow: `text-shadow: 0 0 ;`

---

> also, check out wich is really used https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse
>
> `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`
>
> or
>
> `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

---

```css
div,
p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #4386FC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
p {
  background: #AB0909
}
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  text-shadow: 0 0;
}
caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
table {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 2em, #AB0909 2em, #AB0909 57%, #4386FC 57%);
}
table:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 2em, #AB0909 2em, #AB0909 57%, #4386FC 57%);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<table>
  <caption>be text-shadowed or not</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>text-shadow:0 0</th>
      <th>no text-shadow</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>test font</div>
        <p>test font</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>test font</div>
        <p>test font</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.elfboy.com/blog/text-shadow_anti-aliasing/

Must add font-smoothing property to your text element. generaly visitor view your web page with different browser or device which have their own rendering tech, have you include media query in your stylesheet?